# sed regex cut string

Tags: php, regex, bash, sed, iconv

I have about 200 php files that containing some `iconv()` functions,
something like this:

```
iconv('GB2312','UTF-8',$aRow[$aColumns[3]])
iconv('GB2312','UTF-8',$rs1['supplier']);
iconv('GB2312','UTF-8',$aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]);
```

i don't know what could be the best way to remove `iconv('GB2312','UTF-8',` and final `)` in batch mode without touching the variable.

this RegEx could match my case but i don't know how to use it with `sed`:
`^(iconv\(\'GB2312\'\,\'UTF-8\'\,)+|(\))`

And i am also not sure that `sed` is the right solution in this case

Anyone faced a similar problem before?

Comment: Write a PHP script based on `token_get_all` (see PHP manual and make some tries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
 sed -i "s/iconv('GB2312','UTF-8',\([^)]*\))\(.*\)/\1\2/" file
```

which will extract your php variable into `\1`. `/2` is the remaining of the line (a `;` in the example you posted)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `cut` statement with the output.

```
cat file|cut -d, -f3|tr -d ');'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/iconv('\''GB2312'\'','\''UTF-8'\'',\([^)]*\))/\1/g' file
```

Use an example string as a template, replacing `'` by `'\''` and the variable to be kept as any characters from after the second `,` which is not a closing `)`. This variable is enclosed in quoted `(...)` i.e. `\(...\)` which may be transfered to the RHS of the substitution command as a back reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sed:

```
cat file | sed 's/iconv(.*,.*,\(.*\)).*/\1/g'
```

This will extract only the variable.

Answer (score 0):

With grep

```
grep -o '$[^)]*' infile
```